# ColorSpace Issues Migrating to PDFBox 2.0.x

Tags: pdfbox

Our department has inherited code that uses Apache PDFBox 1.8.x or earlier and we are in the process of trying to migrate it to Apache PDFBox 2.0.x.

I have resolved a lot of the various issues in this migration, but I'm still having problems migrating some of the ColorSpace related code. Below are some examples that I haven't figured out how to resolve. I've used the missing methods as the headings for each code snippet.

**getColorSpaces() and setColorSpace()**

```
public class ColorSpaceSetter extends OperatorProcessor {

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(ColorSpaceSetter.class.getName());

    public void process(Operator operator, List<COSBase> arguments) throws IOException {

        try {
            COSName arg = (COSName)arguments.get(0);

            String argString = arg.getName();
            if (context.getColorSpaces().containsKey(argString)) {
                PDColorSpace colorSpace = context.getColorSpaces().get(argString);
                if (colorSpace.getName().equals(COSName.SEPARATION.getName())) {
                    PDSeparation separation = (PDSeparation)colorSpace;

                    PDColor color;
                    //Non-stroking
                    if (StringUtils.isAllLowerCase(operator.getName())) {
                        color = context.getGraphicsState().getNonStrokingColor();
                    //Stroking
                    } else {
                        color = context.getGraphicsState().getStrokingColor();
                    }
                    color.setColorSpace(separation);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Unexpected argument array for operator " + operator.getName(), e);
        }
    }
}
```

**getColorSpace()**

```
public boolean determineStroking(PDColor color) {
    for ( Float val : color.getColorSpace()) {
        if (val != 1) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

**setColorSpace() and setColorSpaceValue()**

```
public class StrokeSetter extends OperatorProcessor {

    public void process(Operator operator, List<COSBase> arguments) throws IOException {

        //Supported operators are: g, rg, k, sc, and scn
        //g = device gray (black or white)
        //rg = rgb (000 is black, 111 is white, other is some other color)
        //k = cmyk (0 is black, 1 is white, other is some other color)
        //sc and scn = could be anything, but 0 is black, 1 is white)

        boolean blackSeparation = false;

        //Lowercase is non-stroking (fill) color
        PDColor color;
        if (StringUtils.isAllLowerCase(operator.getName())) {
            color = context.getGraphicsState().getNonStrokingColor();
        //Uppercase is stroking color
        } else {
            color = context.getGraphicsState().getStrokingColor();
        }

        //Treat separations differently - see section 4.5.5 of PDF Reference Documentation
        PDColorSpace colorSpace = color.getColorSpace();
        if (colorSpace.getName().equals(COSName.SEPARATION.getName())) {
            PDSeparation separation = (PDSeparation)color.getColorSpace();
            if (separation.getColorantName().equals("Black")) {
                blackSeparation = true;
            }
        }

        //Black and White
        if (operator.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("g")) {
            color.setColorSpace( new PDDeviceGray() );
            float[] values = new float[1];
            if ( arguments.size() >= 1 ) {
                values[0] = ((COSNumber)arguments.get( 0 )).floatValue();
            } else {
                throw new IOException( "Error: Expected at least one argument when setting gray color");
            }
            color.setColorSpaceValue( values );

        //RGB colors
        } else  if (operator.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("rg")) {
            color.setColorSpace(PDDeviceRGB.INSTANCE); 
            float[] values = new float[3];
            for ( int i = 0; i < arguments.size(); i++) {
                values[i] = ((COSNumber)arguments.get( i )).floatValue();
            }
            color.setColorSpaceValue(values);

        //CMYK colors
        } else if (operator.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("k")) {
            color.setColorSpace( PDDeviceCMYK.INSTANCE );
            float[] values = new float[4];
            for( int i=0; i<arguments.size(); i++ )
            {
                values[i] = ((COSNumber)arguments.get( i )).floatValue();
            }
            color.setColorSpaceValue(values);
        // Unspecified ColorSpace
        } else if (operator.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("sc") || operator.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("scn")) {
            int size = arguments.size();
            if ( size == 1) {
                color.setColorSpace(new PDDeviceGray());
            } else if ( size == 3) {
                color.setColorSpace(PDDeviceRGB.INSTANCE);
            } else if ( size == 4) {
                color.setColorSpace(PDDeviceCMYK.INSTANCE);
            } else {
                color.setColorSpace(new PDDeviceN());
            }

            float[] values = new float[size];
            for( int i=0; i<arguments.size(); i++ )
            {
                //Flip values when blackSeparation for PDDeviceGray
                if (blackSeparation & size == 1) {
                    float val = ((COSNumber)arguments.get( i )).floatValue();
                    values[i] = Math.abs(val - 1);
                } else {
                    values[i] = ((COSNumber)arguments.get( i )).floatValue();
                }
            }
            color.setColorSpaceValue(values);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you have problems upgrading with in those code snipplets?

Comment: The best would be to compare the source code of 1.8 with the one of 2.0. `ColorSpaceSetter` seems to be modified from `SetStrokingColorSpace`. In the new sources, `context.getResources().getColorSpace` returns only one colorspace but you only need one anyway. `setColorSpaceValue()` is replaced by `context.getGraphicsState().setStrokingColor()`in the new version.